# Compiler Error when Interface within Inner Class

Tags: java

I want to declare an interface inside an inner class, which shows compiler error message "inner classes cannot have static declarations".

```
public class Apple {       
    //...

    public class InnerApple{
    //...

        public interface InnerInterface{
            //Error: inner classes cannot have static declarations
        }
    }
}
```

Does it mean interface is actually static in Java?

I'm using Java 1.7. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface is always static - in a sense that there cannot be any dependency to another instance.

Having two levels of inner declarations is quite uncommon, but if it is intended I would expect that at least `InnerApple` is **static**:

```
public class Apple {       
  public static class InnerApple{

    public interface InnerInterface{
        //this does not cause an error
    }
  }
}
```

In most cases the keyword **static** of inner classes is omitted. If so this class may contain dependencies to a surrounding instance (and not only to the class as static inner classes do).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, member interfaces are implicitly `static`.  [Section 8.5.1 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1) states:

> A member interface is implicitly static (§9.1.1).

For it not to be static, the interface must be top-level, with no enclosing class or interface.